# Resolving Merge Conflict by pulling only the conflicting file

Tags: git

In case of merge conflict with one object, we generally pull the entire content of the target branch to the feature branch and then resolve the conflicting object. Due to this, the object which is not modified is also commited again in the feature branch.e.g if I have modified 2 objects in my feature branch and want to merge to the release branch(having 20 objects), we generally pull the entire release branch contents and then resolve the conflict for 2 objects.

```
git pull origin <release Branch>
```

The problem is that all the unrelated objects also come in the feature branch. Any easy way to pull only the conflicting object from the release branch.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file
```

Comment: @RahulRaj I am glad to hear that :p, can you upvote my answer.I need some repurations.Thanks